# CSS - a form that fits on dinA4 if printed

Tags: html, css, pdf

I want to style a form, a user can later download as pdf. How do I know the correct size, to make it fit on a dinA4 sheet of paper (21mm x 297mm)? How can I measure when the document will continue on the next page?

HTML

```
<form>
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">

      .....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@page { size: A4 }
```

use with caution — not quite sure if there is any about browser support. you might be fine by just defining margins for your @page and keep the layout responsive.

you also can use [page break properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-breaks) (page-break-before, page-break-after, page-break-inside) to control whether your elements will continue on the next page.